# Testing for nil to determine if a coordinate is on a grid

Tags: ruby, null

In Learn to Program (Chris Pine) there's a challenge to improve a piece of code that calculates contiguous tiles on a grid. The code he gives you will fail if the tiles border the edge of the grid - you need to fix that.

The key is to return `0` if the tile is `o` or if the coordinate you're checking isn't on the grid.

```
M = 'land'
o = 'water'

world = [[o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o],
         [o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o,M,o],
         [o,o,o,M,o,M,M,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,M,M,M,M,o,o,o], 
         [o,o,o,M,M,M,M,M,M,M,o],
         [o,o,o,M,M,o,M,M,M,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,M,M,o,o,o], 
         [o,M,o,o,o,M,o,o,o,o,o],
         [o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o,o]]

def continent_size world, x, y 
  if world[y][x] != 'land'
    # Either it's water or we already
    # counted it, but either way, we don't # want to count it now.
    return 0
  end
```

I've solved this one way, but I want to know why another way isn't working. Here's my working solution:

```
if y > world.length || x > world[y].length || world[y][x] != 'land'
  return 0
end
```

And here's what I tried first, which doesn't work:

```
if world[y][x].nil?
  return 0
elsif world[y][x] != 'land'
  return 0
end
```

In IRB, if I look up a non-existent coordinate like `world[5][15]` the returned value is `nil` so I was expecting `world[y][x].nil?` to work and I don't understand why it doesn't.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will fail when `y` is outside the grid. This is because `world[y]` will be `nil`, which then raises an exception trying to reference `[x]`; i.e. `world[y][x]` would read `nil[x]`.

```
world = [[1]]

world[0][0] # 1
world[0][1] # nil
world[1][0] # NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

For a solution, you could use:

```
def continent_size(world, x, y)
  0 if world[y] && world[y][x] != 'land'
end
```

Comment: @ryancito what values for `x` and `y` did you use?

Comment: Thanks, I get it! When testing in IRB, I was using an example like `world[0][1]` which returned `nil` but in the code things like `world[1][0]` also happen, which produces the error!